# How can I fix the error: "{ "message": "Cannot PUT /app-user", "error": "Not Found", "statusCode": 404 }" while making a POST request in Postman?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, nestjs

**Entity code **

```
   import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column } from 'typeorm';

@Entity({ name: 'app_user' })
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ name: 'user_id' })
  userId: number;

  @Column({ name: 'username', type: 'varchar', length: 255, unique: true })
  username: string;

  @Column({ name: 'user_password', type: 'varchar', length: 255 })
  userPassword: string;

  @Column({ name: 'user_role', type: 'varchar', length: 50 })
  userRole: string;
}
```

**app-service**

```
import { MessageCount } from './entities/message-count';
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';
import { User } from './entities/app-user';

const logger = new Logger('AppService');

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
constructor(private readonly db: DataSource) {}
async appendUser(user: User) {
  // Assuming you have necessary validation or additional logic
  return this.appendUserToDB(user).catch((err) => {
    // Retry in case of an error
    logger.error(err);
    return this.appendUserToDB(user);
  });
}

private appendUserToDB(user: User) {
  return this.db.getRepository(User)
      .save(user)
      .then(() => {
        logger.verbose('User added successfully.');
      });
  
}

getHello(): string {
  return 'Hello World!';
}
}
```

**Controller.ts**

```
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { MessageCount } from './entities/message-count';
import { User } from './entities/app-user';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Get()
  getHello(): string {
    return this.appService.getHello();
  }
@Post('add-user') // Adjust the route as needed
  async addUser(@Body() user: User) {
    try {
      await this.appService.appendUser(user);
      return { message: 'User added successfully' };
    } catch (error) {
      return { message: 'Error adding user', error: error.message };
    }
  }
```

**app-module.ts**

```
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { ConfigManager } from './app.config';
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';

const appConfigMgr = new ConfigManager();
const appDataSource = new DataSource(appConfigMgr.getConfigObject().dbConfig);

@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [
    AppService,
    { provide: ConfigManager, useValue: appConfigMgr },
    { provide: DataSource, useValue: appDataSource },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

When making a POST request in Postman:

`http://localhost:3000/add-user`

With Body request:
{
"username": "admin",
"userPassword": "admin",
"userRole": "admin"
}

I'm getting the issue as:

{
"statusCode": 404,
"message": "Cannot POST /add-user",
"error": "Not Found"
}

I get error this while making a POST request in Postman
How can I fix the error:

Comment: can you share the curl you are using? also pay attention to the logs printed out when starting the server, it prints out all the available exposed endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

you are requesting wrong the url, the url should be:

URL + controller name + path (here the path is add-user)

```
http://localhost:3000/add-user
```

```
{
    "message": "Cannot PUT /app-user",
    "error": "Not Found",
    "statusCode": 404
}
```

that means app-user doesn't have in your controller

Comment: the controller has a decorator "@Controller()" meaning the controller name is empty and therefore the url is supposed to be http://localhost:3000/add-user.

Answer (score 0):

In postman you're requested using **PUT** method and in controller you have define **POST** method.